# Export/Convert PNG to HTML table using GIMP batch mode in Windows 7

Tags: command-line, batch, gimp

I need to convert PNG images to HTML tables in GIMP batch mode from the Windows command line and have been unsuccessful using google to find an example I can reuse.

I can open the PNG in GIMP and then export as htm to get the file I need so I know GIMP can do the job but I need to do this hundreds of times from within another script at the command line so I need help with the syntax.

I know this is completely incorrect but should give an idea of what I am looking for:
gimp-console-2.8.exe -b (convert -format html test.png)

Comment: http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/

Comment: I have read the tutorials on gimp but cannot seem to find the correct function or syntax to save/export an image as an HTML table.